# replace NA with median in pyspark using window function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, window

I want to replace NA with medain based on partition columns using window function in pyspark?

Sample Input:

[image]

Required Output:

[image]

Comment: in the required output, your last value of p_id should be 5, so that median can be computed to be 2, otherwise it does not fall in partition, i have made the change in my solution, posting shortly

Comment: yes you are right it 5 not 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Creating your dataframe:

```
list=([1,5,4],
    [1,5,None],
    [1,5,1],
    [1,5,4],
    [2,5,1],
    [2,5,2],
    [2,5,None],
    [2,5,None],
     [2,5,4])
df=spark.createDataFrame(list,['I_id','p_id','xyz'])
df.show()

+----+----+----+
|I_id|p_id| xyz|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   5|   4|
|   1|   5|null|
|   1|   5|   1|
|   1|   5|   4|
|   2|   5|   1|
|   2|   5|   2|
|   2|   5|null|
|   2|   5|null|
|   2|   5|   4|
+----+----+----+
```

To keep the solution as generic and dynamic as possible, I had to create many new columns to compute the median, and to be able to send it to the nulls. With that said, solution will not be slow, and will be scalable for big data.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
w= Window().partitionBy("I_id","p_id").orderBy(F.col("xyz").asc_nulls_first())
w2= Window().partitionBy("I_id","p_id")
df.withColumn("xyz1",F.count(F.col("xyz").isNotNull()).over(w))\
.withColumn("xyz2", F.max(F.row_number().over(w)).over(w2))\
.withColumn("xyz3", F.first("xyz1").over(w))\
.withColumn("xyz10", F.col("xyz2")-F.col("xyz3"))\
.withColumn("xyz9", F.when((F.col("xyz2")-F.col("xyz3"))%2!=0, F.col("xyz2")-F.col("xyz3")+1).otherwise(F.col("xyz2")-F.col("xyz3")))\
.withColumn("xyz4", (F.col("xyz9")/2))\
.withColumn("xyz6", F.col("xyz4")+F.col("xyz3"))\
.withColumn("xyz7", F.when(F.col("xyz10")%2==0,(F.col("xyz4")+F.col("xyz3")+1)).otherwise(F.lit(None)))\
.withColumn("xyz5", F.row_number().over(w))\
.withColumn("medianr", F.when(F.col("xyz6")==F.col("xyz5"), F.col("xyz")).when(F.col("xyz7")==F.col("xyz5"),F.col("xyz")).otherwise(F.lit(None)))\
.withColumn("medianr2", (F.mean("medianr").over(w2)))\
.withColumn("xyz", F.when(F.col("xyz").isNull(), F.col("medianr2")).otherwise(F.col("xyz")))\
.select("I_id","p_id","xyz")\
.orderBy("I_id").show()

+----+----+---+
|I_id|p_id|xyz|
+----+----+---+
|   1|   5|  4|
|   1|   5|  1|
|   1|   5|  4|
|   1|   5|  4|
|   2|   5|  2|
|   2|   5|  2|
|   2|   5|  1|
|   2|   5|  2|
|   2|   5|  4|
+----+----+---+
```

Comment: can we find approximate median with aprroximatequantile?

Comment: You could use that if you want 1 median for your entire column. Approxquantile is not an aggregate function so you would not be able to put in a window for your use case. @VigneshwarThiyagarajan

Comment: @murtihash, I was trying to understand the answer you were providing, and have some questions on understanding the windows function you wrote. I compiled this in another post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927213/regarding-the-usage-of-f-countf-colsome-column-isnotnull-in-windows-func      would youl like to take a look at it? Thank you.