# regarding the usage of F.count(F.col("some column").isNotNull()) in window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I am trying to test the usage of F.count(F.col().isNotNull()) in window function. Please see the following code script

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
list=([1,5,4],
    [1,5,None],
    [1,5,1],
    [1,5,4],
    [2,5,1],
    [2,5,2],
    [2,5,None],
    [2,5,None],
     [2,5,4])
df=spark.createDataFrame(list,['I_id','p_id','xyz'])
w= Window().partitionBy("I_id","p_id").orderBy(F.col("xyz").asc_nulls_first())
df.withColumn("xyz1",F.count(F.col("xyz").isNotNull()).over(w)).show()
```

The result is shown as follows. In the first two rows, my understanding is that `F.count(F.col("xyz")` should count the non-zero items from `xyz = -infinity` to `xyz = null`, how does the following     `isNotNull()` process this. Why it gets `2` for the first two rows in `xyz1` column.

[image]

Comment: the value None for the column xyz is different from null. isNotNull function would check for null and that is why it gives 2 for the column xyz1 as there are two rows with None value in your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you count the Booleans, since they are either True or False, you will count all the rows in the specified window, regardless of whether `xyz` is null or not.

What you could do is to `sum` the `isNotNull` Boolean rather than counting them.

```
df.withColumn("xyz1",F.sum(F.col("xyz").isNotNull().cast('int')).over(w)).show()
+----+----+----+----+
|I_id|p_id| xyz|xyz1|
+----+----+----+----+
|   2|   5|null|   0|
|   2|   5|null|   0|
|   2|   5|   1|   1|
|   2|   5|   2|   2|
|   2|   5|   4|   3|
|   1|   5|null|   0|
|   1|   5|   1|   1|
|   1|   5|   4|   3|
|   1|   5|   4|   3|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Another way is to do a conditional count using `when`:

```
df.withColumn("xyz1",F.count(F.when(F.col("xyz").isNotNull(), 1)).over(w)).show()
+----+----+----+----+
|I_id|p_id| xyz|xyz1|
+----+----+----+----+
|   2|   5|null|   0|
|   2|   5|null|   0|
|   2|   5|   1|   1|
|   2|   5|   2|   2|
|   2|   5|   4|   3|
|   1|   5|null|   0|
|   1|   5|   1|   1|
|   1|   5|   4|   3|
|   1|   5|   4|   3|
+----+----+----+----+
```